# Error: The navigation property of type 'MVCApp.Models.Order' is not a single implementation of 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T]'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Q: How can I access the following OrderStatusType within my Order object (both in my controller and razor view...using mvc3/ef4.1/.edmx)?  The following code throws the error specified in the Title.

-- Controller Code (errors):

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    Order o = db.Orders.Find(id);
    OrderStatusType os = o.OrderStatusType;  // <= This is throwing!

    return View(o);
}
```

-- Model:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Desc { get; set; }
    public int OrderStatusTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderStatusType OrderStatusType { get; set; }  // Order contains an OrderSTatusType
}

public class OrderStatusType
{
    public int OrderStatusTypeId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

-- Razor (errors):

```
<div class="display-field">
    @Model.OrderStatusType.Name  @* This throws the same error as well *@
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dropping the `Order` and `OrderStatusType` tables from your edmx file, then re-adding them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the following in your OrderStatusType class:

```
public virtual ICollection<Order> Order {get;set;}
```

I have called the property Order but it should be called in the same way as that end on the relationship